# searching a d3 tree - reset after search

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've written a search function to run through a potentially quite big d3 tree and filter out only the nodes matching a search pattern.

The search function works well and is reasonably fast.

But, because of the volume and the time to calculate the data on the server, I want to be able to reset the tree to its initial contents if the user clears the search or enters another one, without making another query.  That is not working.

**This is what I tried:**

## 1 - cloning d3 nodes

First, I took a look at [what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object][1] and they had several recommendations.  Running from Jasmine, my cloning seems to work (not sure why actually).

Running the code in my app, I get an immediate error.  The exact error depends on which code I use - jquery.extend or JSON.parse of JSON.stringify.

I suspect this is because each node d has a d.parent attribute as well as d.children, so it enters a cycle as soon as you want to recursively clone its children.

## 2 - setting d3.layout.tree.children to filter the data.

Then I noticed that there was a d3.layout.tree.children function, which I could use to manipulate the tree.  So, I did that instead of copying the json data and would only return nodes where d.visible  true.  The idea is that I don't have to do anything when I want to reset, I just go back to the base, non-filtering, children.

That doesn't work either - the children nodes not matching the search have now disappeared from the data, not just the graph.

**Update:  I've removed my initial sample code which didn't work and given a tentative first answer myself that works for me.**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most elegant approach, but it works for me.

Basically, I just copy the reference to the existing _nodes before doing a search.  The search recurses through the tree and clones nodes that match the search pattern.  And any nodes with children matching the search pattern.
So clone volume is limited by the match volume.
The cloning code itself is pretty naive - it only deals with primitive values, but that's all I need right now.

Note: _nodes is basically the incoming json data that you see in any online d3 example.

```
//support an array of possible attributes for string matches...
var li_tosearch = ["label"];

//a "set" of node attributes that should not be copied    
s_skip = Object.create(null);
s_skip.parent = 1;
s_skip.children = 1;
s_skip._children = 1;
s_skip._unfiltered_children = 1;


function clone_n_filter(pattern, d) {
    /* recursive search by node 
       - a node is visible if one of its searchable attributes
       matches the pattern or if one of its children/_children is
       visible.
       - only visible nodes get cloned 
    */

    if (!d  || !pattern){
        return;
    }

    var visible_child, clone, v, s;
    var visible = false;


    //support an array of possible attributes for string matches...
    for (var i = 0; i < li_tosearch.length; ++i){
        s = d[li_tosearch[i]];
        if (s){
            if (s.match(pattern)){
                visible = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    var children = [], _children = [];

    //if any of the children are visible then the current is visible too
    if (d.children) {
        for (var index = 0; index < d.children.length; ++index) {
            visible_child = clone_n_filter(pattern, d.children[index]);
            if (visible_child) {
                children.push(visible_child);
                visible = true;
            }
        }
    }


    if (d._children) {
        for (var index2 = 0; index2 < d._children.length; ++index2) {
            visible_child = clone_n_filter(pattern, d._children[index2]);
            if (visible_child) {
                _children.push(visible_child);
                visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //not being used, but keeps track of all original children
    //this is just a reference, so memory cost is low
    //possible use case:  expand a non-leaf node that has
    //no visible children
    d._unfiltered_children = d.children || d._children;

    if (visible){
        clone = d.constructor(); // changed

        for(var key in d) {
            if (key in s_skip){
                continue;
            }

            if(d.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                v = d[key];

                //given the domain, only expecting primitives...
                //will address when that breaks
                if (typeof(v) === 'object'){
                    throw("unexpected complex object:[" + typeof(v) + " " + key + "]");
                }

                clone[key] = v;
            }
            else{
                //keeping track of attributes we won't be copying
                s_skip[key] = 1;
            }
        }
        clone.children = children;
        clone._children = _children;

    }

    return clone;

}
```

The entry point to the whole thing. 
The reset is extremely fast - it just sets _nodes to the original saved reference.

```
_chart.search = function(pattern){
  /* external entry point for calling the search*/

    if (!_nodes){
        return;
    }

    if (!pattern){
        //no search pattern
        if  (_o_nodes){
            //restore unfiltered
            _nodes = _o_nodes;            
        }
        chart.render();
        return;
    }

    if (!_o_nodes){
        //no need to clone the _nodes, just copy reference
        _o_nodes = _nodes;        
    }

    var patre = new RegExp(pattern,"gi");
    _nodes = clone_n_filter(patre, _o_nodes);

    chart.render();
};
```